# serialize form excluding specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to serialize a form in such a way that it will exclude elements from some particular parent. e.g.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="myText" />
    <input type="hidden" name="myHidden" />
    <div class="ng-hide">
        <input type="text" name="insideText" />
    </div>
</form>
```

js code:

```
$('form').serialize(); // it will serialize all elements
```

I want to serialize form's all element excluding parent `div.ng-hide`. Off course before submit I can remove it like `$('.ng-hide').remove()` but needs some better solution.

Note: The example is minified version, there could be 3-4 ng-hide div and inside each there could be 10+ elements –

Comment: `$('form input')` ???

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below:

```
var serializedReturn = $('input[name!=insideText]', this).serialize();
```

Or to be in better way

```
$('form').find('input[name!=insideText]').serialize();
```

or to avoid whole `div`

```
$('form').not('.ng-hide').serialize();
```

Comment: The example is minified version, there could be 3-4 ng-hide div and inside each there could be 10+ elements

Comment: So you can try the last approach!!

Comment: $('form').not('ng-hide') will filter out forms having class ng-hide

Comment: so you want to hide only `div` having class `ng-hide`?

Comment: Yes... I want to exclude elements which are child of div.ng-hide in serialize output

Comment: Then you can try with `$('form').not('div.ng-hide').serialize();` right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('form:not(.ng-hide) > :input').serialize();
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/0myLy6xj/3/)